# Facebook Connect, how to allow users to find and invite friends to your site?

Tags: php, facebook

I've read quite a bit of documentation, and it's all based around on setting up full blown Facebook integration on your site to the point where you're completely relying on Facebook.

All I want to know is 2 things:
1) How do I allow my users to find out which of their Facebook friends have already joined my site
2) And what's the easiest way to let them invite Facebook friends to the site?

The site that does it perfectly and exactly how I want to duplicate is Gowalla at http://gowalla.com/friends/find

Note: I've never used Facebook Connect, however I have an API key somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to become best buddies with the [Facebook Developer Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), especially the [web guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web).

Where you can start is the [Login With Faces plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login), although the [Facepile](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile) could apply as well.  But understand this: If you're not using Facebook to authenticate your users (i.e., using Facebook Connect*), these plugins will be worthless to you.

In terms of inviting people, there's not going to be a great way to do that.  You can implement request forms through the [XFBML ServerFbml tag](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:serverFbml), but that's really for inviting people to other Facebook entities, not your own site.  There's the [share button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/share-button_%28XFBML%29) but that's not really the same thing as an invite.

**Note: It's actually no longer called Facebook Connect - they are slowly moving away from that moniker.  They are moving to the terminology "single sign-on".  However, the "Facebook Connect" name still pops up in many places.*

Comment: Gowalla doesn't seem to be using Facebook to authenticate me does it?

I've been reading things like:http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect/Integrating_an_Invite_Form_into_Your_Website

Which seems to do point 2, however at the bottom it hints at point 1 "Another useful application of invites and requests is the ability to utilize fb:connect-form to automatically associate your users' friends with their Facebook accounts if they have one. This can serve as a useful way for your users to find new friends they didn't know already existed on your site."

But still...

Comment: If you go to http://gowalla.com/ and click the "Sign In" link in the top right corner, you get a login modal that includes a "Connect With Facebook" button.  So, they provide Facebook authentication as an option.