# Where can I learn how to implement an "invite your facebook friends" dialog for a non-canvas application/website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't seem to find an up to date reference on this. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562191/invite-friends-in-a-dialog-in-a-facebook-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990592/facebook-connect-how-to-allow-users-to-find-and-invite-friends-to-your-site) are outdated (FBML is now deprecated), and most everything else I seem to find is more of the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Request Dialog on Website](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9804834/facebook-request-dialog-on-website)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this [Requests Dialog document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)?
It has a good example of how, using the js sdk, you can open the requests dialog, something like:

```
FB.ui({
    method: "apprequests",
    message: "My Great Request",
    to: user_ids
}, requestCallback);
```

Comment: That only works from canvas applications within Facebook. From the documentation you linked to: "Requests are only available for Desktop Canvas apps and not websites. Accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request."

Comment: Um, wait, what is it that you want to invite the users to?